# Finding a minimum value in each column of 8*720 array?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, numpy

I have an array called meanRSS of 8*720 and i want to see the minimum value in each column and subtract that value from other elements of that column. I want to do this for every column.

meanRSS.shape = (8,720)

minInds = meanRSS.argsort()

I don't know how to proceed after this. I'm new to python.

```
Out[13]: 
array([[5, 2, 1],
   [6, 4, 3],
   [1, 6, 8],
   [8, 5, 4]])
In [14]: minInds = a.argsort()
In [15]: minInds
Out[15]: 
array([[2, 1, 0],
   [2, 1, 0],
   [0, 1, 2],
   [2, 1, 0]])
```

But i want it sorted along columns not rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `min()` method on your array with `axis = 0` to find out a vector of column minimums and then subtract it from your original array:

```
arr - arr.min(axis = 0)

#array([[4, 0, 0],
#       [5, 2, 2],
#       [0, 4, 7],
#       [7, 3, 3]])
```

Comment: thanks a lot. But will this line work for my 8*720 array or do i have to use a for loop to calculate this for every column in it?

Comment: It should work for 2D array(matrix) no matter what the dimension would be.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try something like transposing the matrix, subtracting the min val from all greater values in the column and transposing back. for example

```
>>> transpose = lambda matrix: list(map(list, zip(*matrix)))
>>> col_min_min = lambda col: [(val-min(col) if val !=min(col) else val) for val in col]
>>>
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
>>> result = transpose([col_min_min(col) for col in transpose(a)])
>>> print result
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]
```